# Docker-Compose file has yaml.scanner.ScannerError : mapping values are not allowed here

Tags: networking, docker-compose, yaml, external

My objective is to use 1 bridge network in docker for all my docker-compose on the same host, for all my domains.

I have configured 3 yml file for my docker-compose infrastructure and I'm using 1 external bridge network dockerprometheus_back-tier for all of them. 
One YAML file for reverse proxy (traefik) and one YAML file for each domain name (2 files).

Each time I'm trying to stop & start the last YAML with the command `docker-compose -f mail.yml down && docker-compose -f mail.yml up -d`, I got :

```
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
```

After commenting most of the commands in the yml 3, I understand that the problem is when I add the line `name: dockerprometheus_back-tier`

But in the 2 other yml files, I already did exactly the same configuration to use this network and the yaml processor doesn't complain.

YAML 1

```
version: '3'

networks:
  internal:
    external: false
  prometheus:
    external: true
      name: dockerprometheus_back-tier
```

YAML 2

```
version: '3'

networks:
  onlyinternal:
    driver: bridge
    external: false
  prometheus:
    external: true
      name: dockerprometheus_back-tier
```

```
docker network ls
04e3348408c4        dockerprometheus_back-tier    bridge              local
```

I applied dos2unix to clean the encoding on the YAML 3 but doesn't change anything. I made a copy directly of the YAML 3, keeping the first lines, and trying to start it but it failed too with same error. Is there a limitation in docker to use 3 times the same bridge network from external files? How to solve it?

Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4 , CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

YAML 3:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  mail_network:
    driver: bridge
    external: false
  prometheus:
    external: true
      name: dockerprometheus_back-tier
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Indicating blocks of code is best done by indenting the block four spaces (use: Ctrl+K on the block). Your use of triple back quotes gobbled the text following on the line (`version: 3`), now it shows. You should also note that the file format is YAML and the recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since 2006.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three YAML documents you present have the same problem and are all invalid.

As value for the key `external` you have a multi-line unquoted scalar

```
true name: dockerprometheus_back-tier
```

within an unquoted scalar you cannot have a value indicator followed by whitespace as this might indicate a new key. Either quote the multi-line scalar:

```
networks:
  mail_network:
    driver: bridge
    external: false
  prometheus:
    external: "true
      name: dockerprometheus_back-tier"
```

Or if `name` should be a key at the same level as `external`, make sure it is indented as such:

```
networks:
  mail_network:
    driver: bridge
    external: false
  prometheus:
    external: true
    name: dockerprometheus_back-tier
```

You can have something like the following in YAML:

```
  prometheus:
    external:
      name: dockerprometheus_back-tier
```

but of course a key cannot both have, as value, a scalar node (`true`) **and** a mapping node ('name: dockerprometheus_back-tier')

Comment: so my case is solved, thanks to you Anthon!  
2 remarks following your answer : 
--> why does your last solution work ? because there is an "implicit blank" scalar node for "external" key ?
--> do you know a good cmd-line yml editor on linux, to help to avoid this situation ?

Comment: I don't know about an editor, but if you have python3, you can install my ruamel.yaml library and do `python3 -c "from pathlib import Path; from ruamel.yaml import YAML; YAML().load(Path('3.yaml'))"`, which will at least get you the line number and column in `3.yaml` where the error occurs.